# SignalR Negotiate 404 on Subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've created a small MVC SignalR app which I'm having trouble running on my server under a subdomain:
http://chat.mydomain.com, which maps to a folder called /chat.

I've also made a console program using SignalR Client which connects and works perfectly, strangely enough.

The error from the MVC app is a 404 from http://chat.mydomain.com/chat/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=[...]. I can see why this is happening but have no idea how to fix it. In my generated hubs file, the line

```
signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/chat/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
```

is technically correct, but should read `$.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });`

Any ideas on how to alter this? Or should I just use the raw connection API.

Also why does it work properly from the console app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue to use the generated hubs file. You just need to modify the hubConnection's url (which stored at `$.connection.hub.url`) before you start your SignalR connection.

```
// This is initially set to "/chat/signalr" as specified in the hubs file
$.connection.hub.url = "/signalr";
$.connection.hub.start()...
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer, I tried quite a few different urls before enabling deciding to enable jsonp and using _'//mydomain.com/chat/signalr'_ as the url and it worked! It feels a bit hacky doing it this way but at least it works!