# SignalR Error 500 on server - asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, internal-server-error

I have a simple chat application that works fine locally, but the SignalR throws an internal server error remotely.

The script that throws the error looks like this:

> http://mydomainname.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData...

Here is the log:
[image]

I have looked at other answers on a similar topic but none seem to work for me.
These are the answers I referenced: [SignalR Negotiate 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910943/signalr-negotiate-404), [SignalR Negotiate 404 on Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879633/signalr-negotiate-404-on-subdomain).

Here is the client code:

```
$(function () {
                // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
                $.connection.hub.url = 'http://mydomainname.com/signalr';
                $.connection.hub.logging = true;

                var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

                var name = '<%= username%>'
                // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
                chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                    // Add the message to the page.
                    bootbox.alert({
                        message: "<b>" + name + "</b>: " + message,
                    });
                };

                chat.client.sendMessage = function (name, message) {
                    // Add the message to the page.
                    $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                       + '</strong>: ' + $('#message').val() + '</li>');
                };
                // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                   // code to append message omitted.
                });
});
```

On navigating to the error link I get a Cryptographic Exception as shown here: [SignalR CryptographicException on AzureWebsites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393684/signalr-cryptographicexception-on-azurewebsites). Is there a solution to this problem?

I'm using asp.net 4.5 and SignalR 2. I have tried lots of things and I'm not sure why the internal server error exists. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show exception details. `Protocol error: Unknown transport.` is normal since the server is looking for the transport. Navigate to: `http://mydomainname.com/signalr/negotiate` and you should get 500.

Comment: @Pawel ah yes sorry, should've included that. I get a Cryptographic Exception as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393684/signalr-cryptographicexception-on-azurewebsites. But not sure of the correct solution in this case.

Comment: You probably don't have the machineKey configured.

Comment: @Pawel thanks, it seems that it was something related to the machineKey. I just added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb package and it's good now.

Comment: This does not seem to be right. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb is an ASP.NET Core package and SignalR 2 is not Core.

Comment: Good point, that did however solve my issue. Now that you point it out, not sure why that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Pawel said in the comment above, the problem was with the `http://mydomainname.com/signalr/negotiate` returning a 500 error: Cryptographic Exception in this case.

I managed to solve this by adding the  Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb package - as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey